# Why does the first block stop executing (Uncaught TypeError), while the second one doesn't (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError)?

Tags: javascript, promise

Pretty much the title:

In my first example I'm trying to call `forEach` on an object, then `console.log` afterwards, and what happens is that the execution stops before it hits `console.log`:

```js
({}).forEach(console.log)
console.log('a')
```

In my second example, I'm trying to do that inside Promises Executors, and it turns out that `console.log('a')` is still executed!

```js
new Promise(() => ({}).forEach(console.log))

new Promise(() => console.log('a'))
```

Why's that?

Thanks

Comment: If you add a `.catch()` to the promise, you'll see the error there, as the promise will reject when an error occurs

Comment: Second one is a promise which is asynchronous.

Comment: Promises executors are synchronous though, aren't they?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Yes, but the catch synchronous exceptions as well.